# Yellow nozzle of my printer is 50% clogged. How to send signal to printer to intense the color by x2?

Tags: printer, color-profiles, cmyk

My yellow water-based ink printhead is 50% usable (print only 50% intensity).

- I have done a lot of deep cleaning (100+), but it didn't work.
- I have cleaned it with hot water, alcohol, and soap.

After many years, all of my printheads are decayed in the similar manner.

How to save the world by continuing using the printhead (Canon MP287) with its half-working status?

## My workarounds

(1)  Use manual color adjustment.  (The result is improved but still not enough)  ::-

[image]

(2)  Write a program to convert every pixel of input images to **CMYK**.  Then double **Y** amount.  After that, convert it back to **RGB**.

- However, the **Y** value of most yellow pixels become overflowed and virtually bounded back to 1 when converted back to **RGB**.
- In the final result, using half broken yellow print head, it just prints half density of **Y**.
- (2B)  Also divide CMYK of every pixel by 1.5, then tell the printer to use intensity =+50%.   Below is the image conversion result.   The printed result is the same as (2).

[image]

(3) Directly ask the printer to print yellow twice by using a hacked **color profile**, but how?

(4) Directly ask the printer to **print the CMYK image**.  Some pixel of the image may have Y>100%.  Is it even possible?

Comment: How about using some rubbing alcohol to clean the nozzle instead?

Comment: It can also be that a wire or element in the print-head is broken. Considering the cost of ink, it might be cheaper to replace the printer (currently ~US$60 in foreign markets) with a different model. You might check the printhead cable for breaks, but I'm not sanguine it's user fixable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum ink that the printer can put out is one drop per pixel per nozzle. If only half the nozzles are working (I assume that is what you mean by "50% usable"), there is no way the others nozzles can produce 2 drops ink to make up for the missing ones. 100% is the maximum.

In addition to that, if not all jets are working, you will see stripes in the output. That might not be too bad if the good and bad nozzles exactly alternate - when printing solid yellow you will see thin yellow lines. If a nozzle could put down more ink, it would still be in the wrong place. The stripes will be a lot worse, with wider yellow and white lines, if the good nozzles are grouped together.

EDIT

As @DrMoishePippik stated in a comment, it's probably cheaper to get a new printer. And, unless you require full photo quality (on special paper), think of getting a laser and avoiding all the inkjet hassles. Yes, they're more expensive to buy, but you'll save money (and frustration) in the long run.

Comment: Thank!  The answer is very useful and will stop me from hacking it pointlessly.  ^^